# Different types of creating functions for javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between this:

```
function Hero(options) {
  options = options || {}
  this.nickname = options.nickname || 'Default 1';
  this.hp = options.hp || '50'
}

Hero.prototype.walk = function() {
  console.log('Hero walked');
}
```

And this:

```
function Hero(options) {
  options = options || {}
  this.nickname = options.nickname || 'Default 1';
  this.hp = options.hp || '50'

  this.walk = function() {
    console.log('Hero walked')
  }
}
```

Are there any significative gains in using `prototype`?

Comment: Yes, the `walk` method is only created once and shared by all `Hero` instances

Comment: The second one is invalid syntax.

Comment: @SLaks How so? I think I just saw an edit, but not sure what changed

Comment: Oh, there is a similar question. Nevermind to answer then! =]

Answer (score 0):

Methods defined with `Hero.prototype.myMethod = function() {}` will also be be accessible by objects that are children of `Hero`.